# UI for dynamically adding multiple values like the LinkedIn skills section in Grails

Tags: ajax, grails, grails-2.3

I have recently started developing web applications using Grails. I just wanted to know how can I convert the multi-selection list provided by Grails scaffolding for many-to-many relations (where you hold `Ctrl` to add multiple values), to something where I add one value at a time and it has a `X` to remove the added value and a `+` to add more. Something similar to the skills section of LinkedIn or the way we add tags in StackOverflow while asking questions.

[image: LinkedIn Skills section]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would keep the multi-select boxes as they are provided by Grails, but would then use [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) (a javascript library) to make them nicer.